# c++ Interprocesses communication

Tags: c++, process, communication

- I need to write two c++ programs P1 and P2 that will be running on a Windows OS.
- P1 will start first.
- P1 will start P2 (using `CreateProcess()` from `processthreadsapi.h`).
- Every 30 minutes P2 will signal (send a message to) P1.
- P1 contains a function F that will start when P1 receives the signal (message) from P2.

As P1 will start P2, I imagine P2 will know about P1 and will be able to signal it (send it a message) easily...

Can you tell me what would be the easiest approach to implement this mechanism?

The important point, for me in this post, is what is the easiest mechanism for sending a message from P2 to P1.

Using the `CreateProcess()` function, info. can be sent to the child process.
Can this info be the "identity" of the parent process (PPID) so that the child process can send it messages?

Thank you.

Comment: Can it be thread, instead of process?

Comment: Hi. I think a process rather than a thread.

Answer (score 2):

For the problem you have described I would use  anonymous pipes for interprocess communication.

Here is a whole article on Windows IPC that you should read :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications#using-pipes-for-ipc

Comment: Thank you. I think this is a good suggestion. I just made some promissing tests using this code: https://www.ownedcore.com/forums/world-of-warcraft/world-of-warcraft-bots-programs/wow-memory-editing/902618-c-using-ipc-via-named-pipes-example-client-server-setup.html

Comment: Actually, I think (but I am not sure) that pipes are blocking objects (in the example I posted, they are blocking).
What I mean is that P1 and P2 CANNOT do "something" other than communicating via their pipes with each other.
What I need is P1 to be able to do other "things", his "things".
And when "something" happens that P2 is capable of detecting, P2 sends a message to P1.
P1 receives this message. And this message reception provokes the execution of function F().

Comment: @Lea Just create new thread and do whatever you want on it

Comment: Thanks. I was willing P1 and P2 to "independent" from each other (apart from the inter-processes communication of course). If P2 is a P1's thread I am not so sure they are really "independent" from each other (in terms of memory sharing, OS management, ...).
That would probably requires a comparison between the two. Also, I guess it depends on what P2 does. For me, P2 is to implement a TCP socket.

Comment: @Lea You can create new threads in each process. P1 : In one thread process IPC messages and in other do whatever stuff you need. Same for P2.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to solve my problem using threads.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you tell me what would be the easiest approach to implement this mechanism?

1. Write a program which listen for a connection (Server).
2. Write a programm that connects to the Server (Client).
3. Start the Server from the Client and send a message.